# Python: Replacing a simple string?

Tags: python, string

I want to expand "Dr." into either "Doctor" or "Drive" to clear the confusion.

```
string = 'Dr. Seuss Dr.'
if string[0:3] == "Dr.":
    new_string = 'Doctor Seuss Dr.'
if string[:3] == "Dr.":
    another_string = 'Dr. Seuss Drive'
```

Is there a better way to expand out "Dr."?  I can't handle cases if the string is 'I like Dr. Seuss'!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this for a toy program/exercise, or for real-world use?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
mystring = 'Dr. Seuss Dr.'
if 'Dr.' in mystring:
    mystring = mystring.replace('Dr.', 'Doctor', 1).replace('Dr.', 'Drive')
```

The first replace only replaces `Dr.` once (notice the extra parameter added).

Thanks to shantanoo for pointing out that there is a module `string` and so variable names should avoid such word. I have changed the variable to `mystring`.

Comment: +1 It's easy to forget that `.replace` takes a count parameter

Comment: But that would expand "Manor Dr." to "Manor Doctor", wouldn't it?

Comment: @NPE Well the question isn't clear. How do we know what is Doctor and what is Drive? I don't think the OP was intending to imply that the position in the string mattered, and maybe that his use of string slicing was the only method he/she could think of.

Comment: @Haidro: I agree that the question is not entirely clear. However, it seems reasonably clear that, for example, 'Doctor Seuss Dr.' should expand to 'Doctor Seuss Drive' and not to 'Doctor Seuss Doctor'.

Comment: [string](http://docs.python.org/library/string) is the python module. Its better not to use it as variable.

Comment: @NPE Hmm, I guess so. Also, yes it seems reasonable to change the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want to convert `Dr.` into `Doctor` if it is at the beginning of the string. Otherwise, you want `Dr.` to be converted into `Driver`.

You can use regex to achieve this:

```
import re
string = 'Dr. Seuss Dr.'
string = re.sub(re.compile('^Dr.'), 'Doctor', string)
string = re.sub(re.compile('Dr.$'), 'Driver', string)
#now string contains 'Dr. Seuss Drive'
```